# How to create a setter in a model object that would update indexedDB in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm trying to create an object which when any properties are set would update its corresponding indexedDB data automatically.

The following code works as intended but each time that I'm calling the object from the indexedb. I need to create the object as

> new
> ResultsModel(indexedDbData._scores,indexedDbData._overallScore,indexedDbData.id)

Which seems an "anti-pattern" as I'm calling what would be "private" variables even if at this point it's just data.

Is that an issue?
I'm also not sure about setting up "setter" and "getter" ? Should I just create "update" function at this point ?

What would be a good pattern to achieve this ?

```
export class ResultsModel{
    constructor(scores,overallScore, id){       
        this._scores = scores; 
        this._overallScore = overallScore;
        this.id = id;
    }

    async init(){           
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastResults", JSON.stringify(this));    
        await this.save();
    }

    async save(){               
        let req = await db.transaction("moodResults","readwrite").objectStore("moodResults").put(this);
        req.onsuccess = function(event) {console.log("saved")}
        req.onerror = function(event) {console.log("error")}        
    }

    get scores(){
        return this._scores;
    }

    get overallScore(){
        return this._overallScore;
    }

    set scores(newValue){
        this._scores = newValue;
    }

    set overallScore(newValue){         
        this._overallScore = newValue;
        if(this.overallScore === undefined){return}

        return (async () =>{
            let objectStore = await db.transaction("moodResults","readwrite").objectStore("moodResults");
            const req = await objectStore.get(parseInt(this.id));              

            req.onsuccess = async () =>{
                if(req.result === undefined){
                    throw new Error("Object with specified key not found");
                }

                const data = req.result;                            
                data._overallScore = newValue;
                
                const updateOverallScore = objectStore.put(data)

                updateOverallScore.onsuccess = () =>{
                    console.log("update worked")
                }
                updateOverallScore.onerror = () =>{
                    console.log("update didn't worked")
                }
            }

            req.onerror = () =>{
                console.log("getting object didn't work")
            }
        })()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `indexedDbData` come from? Where is that code that you don't like located? It's not part of the snippet that you posted.

Comment: "*I'm trying to create an object which when any properties are set would update its corresponding indexedDB data automatically*" - I would strongly advise against doing that. Updating indexedDb is asynchronous and might fail, a setter should not do that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion indexedDbData would just come from a call to the indexedDB (i.e.  const data in the setter) 

But thanks for the answer, it seems obvious that it was a bad idea to begin with when you said it :) I'll do a separate update function. Thanks